# PermissionError: [Errno 13] when I tried to copy all pdf files into a new folder

Tags: python

I am trying to copy all pdf files within the `source_folder` and its subfolders to a new folder, `target_folder`. It worked to some extent (hundreds of pdf files were found and copied into the `target_folder`), but stopped with an error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "H:\\all_pdf_files\\xyz.pdf"`

I knew that there were some similar issues posted on Stack overflow, I tried some solutions I found. But they didn't help. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

```
import os, shutil
    
source_folder = r'C:\Users\ABC\DEF\GHI'
target_folder = r'H:\all_pdf_files'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(target_folder, file))
```

Comment: A file may be open by another application.

Comment: @pavel, thanks for answering my question. I am sure that file was not opened. I even restarted my laptop and reran the scripts :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my scripts with a try statement included. Although I still don't know how to solve the error issue, running the following scripts can get around the error and print out file names that are not copied.

```
import os, shutil

source_folder = r'C:\Users\ABC\DEF\GHI'
target_folder = r'H:\all_pdf_files'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(target_folder, file))
            except:
                print(os.path.join(root, file))
                print(file)
```